# How to split a signal into parts. VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have an 8-bit input at some point in my code, and I want to separate this input into 2 bit pieces.  The problem is that I can't use a variable and I have to use signal.  If i is a integer everything works fine.  How can I do this if i is a signal?

```
  signal part : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
  signal i    : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);

begin

  part <= d_in(i downto i-1);
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why your signal `i` can't be of type `integer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these analyze  I ran the last one to make sure there wasn't a run time error.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity part_type_range is
end entity;

architecture fum of part_type_range is
    signal part:        std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    signal i:           std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    signal part1:       std_logic_vector (2 downto 1);
begin
    part  <= i(part1'range);
    part1 <= i(part1'range);
end architecture;

architecture fee of part_type_range is
    signal part:        std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    signal i:           std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    subtype partfield is  std_logic_vector (2 downto 1);
begin
    part <= i(partfield'range);
end architecture;

architecture twobitpieces of part_type_range is
    signal part1, part2, part3, part4:  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal i:       std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    type union8 is array (1 to 4) of std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal part:    union8;
begin
    part <= union8'(i(7 downto 6),i(5 downto 4),i(3 downto 2),i(1 downto 0));
    -- part1 <= part(1);
    -- part2 <= part(2);
    -- part3 <= part(3);
    -- part4 <= part(4);  
       -- or in the alternative:
    (part1,part2,part3,part4) <= part;
       -- or use part(N) directly
end architecture;

architecture fie of part_type_range is


    signal part1, part2, part3, part4:  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal i:       std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    type union8 is array (1 to 4) of std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal part:    union8;
    function to_union8 (a: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)) return union8 is
        subtype part1 is std_logic_vector (7 downto 6);
        subtype part2 is std_logic_vector (5 downto 4);
        subtype part3 is std_logic_vector (3 downto 2);
        subtype part4 is std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    begin
        return union8'(a(part1'range),a(part2'range),a(part3'range),a(part4'range));
    end function;
begin
    part <= to_union8(i);
    -- part1 <= part(1);
    -- part2 <= part(2);
    -- part3 <= part(3);
    -- part4 <= part(4);  
       -- or in the alternative:
    (part1,part2,part3,part4) <= part;
       -- or use part(N) directly
end architecture;    

architecture foo of part_type_range is


    signal part1, part2, part3, part4:  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal i:       std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    type union8 is array (1 to 4) of std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    function to_union8 (a: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)) return union8 is
    begin
        return union8'(a(7 downto 6),a(5 downto 4),a(3 downto 2),a(1 downto 0));
    end function;
begin
    part1 <= to_union8(i)(1);
    part2 <= to_union8(i)(2);
    part3 <= to_union8(i)(3);
    part4 <= to_union8(i)(4);
end architecture;
```

And in Brian's parlance the conversion to a union of 4 two bit values and the input eight bit value assigns meaning to i without using unsigned.

Comment: you just gave me an idea!:)

Comment: It was intended to seed ideas.

Comment: And where is `architecture fum`?

Comment: @BrianDrummond The first one below the entity

Answer (score 1):

VHDL is a strong type language, so it requires an `integer` type as index for
`std_logic_vector`, so `std_logic_vector` can't be used directly.

You can convert the index in `i` to integer through use of the
`ieee.numeric_std` library.  See example below:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture sim of tb is

  signal d_in : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  signal part : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  signal i    : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  signal msb  : integer;  -- MSB index value

begin

  msb <= to_integer(unsigned(i));

  part <= d_in(msb downto msb - 1);

end architecture;
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't use integers at all because the board I am using doesn't let it. :/

Comment: Sounds a little odd, since integer is required in VHDL, and you are using plenty of integers in the code already ;-)  What board and tools (compiler) are you using ?

Comment: I haven't use any integers so far and my project is pretty big!:) My board is ZYNQ 7000 I think, as part of my thesis. The tools, I don't know them yet!

Comment: OK, let me elaborate.  The `msb` declared as integer is just an explicit way of creating the index value for use in `d_in`.  So you can actually expand `msb` directly in `d_in` as `part <= d_in(to_integer(unsigned(i)) downto to_integer(unsigned(i)) - 1);`, and then remove the `msb` declaration and assign.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that std_logic_vector is just a "bag of bits" with no inherent meaning. It could mean an instruction, a piece of text, or a signed or unsigned number.

The normal approach is to use `numeric_std.unsigned` instead of `std_logic_vector` for `i`, as in `signal i    : unsigned (2 downto 0);` which assigns meaning to those bits. Then you can write `part <= d_in(to_integer(i) downto to_integer(i)-1)` which works, but is ugly. An intermediate signal of integer type is probably cleaner.

Good use of VHDL involves designing the types you will use before getting into this mess; it won't eliminate type conversions completely but it'll reduce them to a minimum, e.g. at interfaces between blocks.

Comment: The problem is that integers and in general variables aren't synthesizable, and my project has to be synthesizable. So I guess I have to start thinking alternatives so that I won't need to use the   d_in(i downto i-1); part.

Comment: Where did you learn that integers and variables aren't synthesisable? Serious question : it is possible someone is teaching nonsense, because they most certainly are synthesisable. If you are declaring an integer for synthesis, place a range on it so that synth won't try to implement it as 32 bits.

Comment: This project is part of my thesis and my teacher says for the project, which I am constructing, I can't use integers because they are not synthesizable. Maybe it has to do something with the board.

Comment: @user2916486 - your teacher must be very out of date (or the tools you have access to!)  Integers have be synthesisable for as long as I've been writing VHDL (which was in 1997 IIRC)